# Extract sub array for python array with a given step

Tags: python, arrays

I want to extract (x,y,z) from my X array in this way in python:

```
In : X = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  
Out : x = [0, 3, 6]  
y = [1, 4, 7]  
y = [2, 5, 8]
```

Here is my code but it does not give me the right result:

```
import numpy as np
X = range(0,9);
x = np.zeros(3);
y=x;  
z=x;  
print(X);  
for i in range(3):  
    x[i] = X[3*i];  
    for j in range(3):  
        y[j] = X[3*i+j];  
        for k in range(3):  
            z[k] = X[3*j+k];  
print(x);
print(y);
print(z);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spam = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
eggs = [spam[idx::3] for idx in range(3)]
print(eggs)
```

output

```
[[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
```

of course you can unpack the list of lists into 3 separate variables

As an alternative you may use 3rd party-package [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) with same result:

```
import more_itertools
spam = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
eggs = [list(item) for item in more_itertools.distribute(3, spam)]
print(eggs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @buran ! This will give a 3x3 array if I understand?